# jquery < than and > than .width

Tags: jquery, css, width

I'm not sure the best way to describe this. But I'm finding the image width and if its less than 200px it's applying an under-200 class to the parent div.

```
$('.content').find('img').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
        if (width < 200) {
        $(this).parents('.container').addClass('under-200');
        }
});
```

CSS: `.container.under-200 {width: 200px}`

This works fine but I'm having difficulty with applying a width with larger images.

So for a 600px image the jquery applies a 600px width to the parent div, or a 434px image applies a 434px width to the parent div.

Comment: @Cadence96 If you only want the direct parent, yes, it's parent(). If you want to continue upwards, it's parents() (or closest())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parents('.container').css("width", width);
```

Also, use `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

`.parents()` will go through the DOM all the way to the root element, HTML, and THEN filter the result based on your selector. `.closest()`, on the other hand, will stop as soon as a match is found.

You could boil all your code down to a single line:

```
$(this).closest('.container').css("width", (width < 200 ? 200 : width ) );
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Simple and easy to understand! Thank you very much. `.closest()` must be quicker `.parents()`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) has a [setter form](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2), so you can write:

```
$(".content img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $containers = $this.parents(".container"),
        width = $this.width();
    if (width < 200) {
        $containers.addClass("under-200");  // Set class.
    } else {
        $containers.width(width);           // Set width.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Frédéric, very easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should parse the 'width' to an int? so that

```
if (width < 200)
```

works and only returns true if width is indeed less than 200. I can imagine that it now always returns true since width is a string?

Comment: `.width()` returns a number. (second the motion) *The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.* http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I knew it returns no units, but is it always an Integer, i.e. never a String or Float? A float should not be a problem though.